# Is it a bad practice to add reference to a Javascript object in one of its attributes?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a setup like this.

```
var Account = function(data) {
  this.data = data;
  this.domElement = (function(){ code that generates DOM element that will represent this account })();
  this.domElement.objectReference = this;
}

Account.prototype = {
  show: function() { this.domElement.classList.remove('hidden'); },
  hide: function() { this.domElement.classList.add('hidden') }
}
```

My question is about the last line: `this.domElement.objectReference = this;`

It would be a useful thing to have because then I can add event listeners to my DOM element and still get access to the object itself.  I can add methods that would affect my DOM element, such as hide() and show(), for instance, without having to resort to modifying visibility of the DOM element using CSS directly.

I tested this code and it works like I want it to, but I'm curious whether this would cause memory leaks or some other unpleasantness or if it's an acceptable thing to do?

Thank you!
Luka

Comment: I don't see how this is useful...

Comment: Loops like this can cause grief if the only garbage collection mechanism is reference counting. But I assume most JS implementations are more sophisticated than that.

Comment: @elclanrs - It seems to me it is useful because I can then define custom methods relevant to my particular elements, which would result in cleaner code. I suppose I could've done the same thing by doing hide(element) and show(element), but I wanted to try and use prototypes.

Comment: @Why not have `domElement` as a `var`, do `if (this instanceof Account) domElement.objectReference = this;` and `return domElement;` instead? Saves you circular references, lets you access both the _Node_ and the _Object_, helps you sleep at night.

Comment: @PaulS., do you mind posting a full code, please?

Comment: @Lukich I think you have design issues. The Account should be responsible for adding listeners to it's own element. An external class shouldn't have to know the DOM structure of the Account or everything will be tighlty coupled. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @plalx - it's true, I can assign event listeners inside the object, but that would mean one listener per instance. I was trying to figure out of there's a way to delegate event handling to a single listener, yet still have access to the object through it's DOM representative.

Comment: @Lukich, You can always use the same approach they used in jQuery. You  store instances in a map giving them a unique id and then you store that unique id in a data attribute on the DOM element. When you want to retrive the instance from the handler, you just do something like `Account.getInstanceById(this.getAttribute('data-instance-id'))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this has been answered by @PaulS. already, but I find the answer counter intuitive (returning a DOM element from the Account constructor is not expected) and too DOM-centric, but at the same time the implementation is very simple, so I am not sure what to think ;)

Anyway, I just wanted to show a different way of doing it. You can store `Account` instances in a map and give them a unique `id` (perhaps they have one already), then you store that `id` as a data attribute on the DOM element. Finally you implement a `getById` function or something similar to retrieve the account instance by `id` from the listeners.

That's pretty much how jQuery's [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) works.

Here's an example with delegated events like you wanted from the comments.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jZHqZ/)**

```
var Account = (function (accounts, id) {

    function Account(data) {
        accounts[this._id = ++id] = this;

        this.el = createEl.call(this);
    }

    Account.prototype = {
        constructor: Account,
        show: function() { this.el.classList.remove('hidden'); },
        hide: function() { this.el.classList.add('hidden'); }
    };

    function createEl() {
        var el = this.el = document.createElement('div');
        el.className = 'account';
        el.innerHTML = el.dataset.accountId = this._id;

        return el;
    }

    Account.getById = function (id) {
        return accounts[id];
    };

    Account.init = function () {
        //add delegate listeners

        document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            var target = e.target,
                account = Account.getById(target.dataset.accountId);

            if (!account) return;

            account.hide();
        });
    };

    return Account;
})({}, 0);

//once DOM loaded
Account.init(); //start listening to events

var body = document.body;

body.appendChild(new Account().el);
body.appendChild(new Account().el);
```

Comment: I actually prefer this to my own answer, the only danger is it never seems to free the memory; you'd need to add another function to delete from the `accounts` object.

Comment: @PaulS. Yes, I haven't implemented any API that allows to free memory in the example, however it would obviously be important to have something in place in a real world implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Why not have `domElement` as a `var`iable, and `return` it from your *function*? To keep the reference to your *constructed Object* (but only where `this` is as expected), you could do a `if (this instanceof Account) domElement.objectReference = this;`

You've now saved yourself from circular references and can access both the *Node* and the *Object*. Doing it this way around is more helpful if you're expecting to lose the direct reference to your *Account* instance, but expect to need it when "looking up" the *Node* it relates to at some later time.

[Code as requested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460530/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-add-reference-to-a-javascript-object-in-one-of-its-attri#comment28858348_19460530)

```
var Account = function (data) {
    var domElement; // var it
    this.data = data;
    domElement = (function(){/* ... */}()); // use var
    if (this instanceof Account)
        domElement.objectReference = this; // assign `this`
    return domElement;
};
// prototype as before
```

Returned element is now the *Node*, not the *Object*; so you'd access the *Account* instance like this

```
var domElement = new Account();
domElement.objectReference.show(); // for example
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you, it looks like what I was after.  Do you mind clarifying one point for me, though?  Why do I have to perform the instanceof check? Wouldn't this always be instanceof Account inside the constructor?

Comment: @Lukich: if it wasn't called using `new Account` (i.e. `var x = Account();`), that wouldn't be the case.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Yeah but in that case the global namespace would already be polluted by a `data` property ;) `instanceof Account` doesn't seem to make much sense the way it's used here, unless I missed something. Anyway, with tools like JSHint, there's no need for such checks.

Comment: @PaulS - just for completeness sake,incase someone needs this, the prototype would not be the same as before because I cannot access private variables from the constructor.  So, I would have to put my domElement in a closure in the constructor: this.getEl = function(){return domElement;} and then in prototype.hide do something like this.getEl().classList.add('hidden');

Comment: @Lukich If you have a closure over the DOM element it will create a circular reference.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion there is nothing good about referencing the object inside of the object itself. The main reason for this is complexity and obscurity.

If you would point out how exactly are you using this `domElement.objectReference` later in the code, I am sure that I or someone else would be able to provide a solution without this reference.